# Subtract Time on Laravel Views

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, view, strtotime

So here is my code

```
    @foreach($myquery as $mydate)
    <tr>
        <td>{{date('l',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{date('jS F, Y',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{date('h:i A',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{date('h:i A',strtotime($mydate->logoff))}}</td>
        <td>{{$mydate->logon->diff($mydate->logoff)}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

What I want to do is to get the difference of logon and logoff. I just get error 500 with this code, please help

Comment: Please go to your `app/config/app.php` and change `debug` to `true` and update your question with the actual error message.

Comment: its already set to true sir

Comment: So what's the error message then? Without it it's hard to know what's going on.

Comment: sorry, but this is what i just get Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 500

Comment: I found out the answer, mydate from database is not yet converted to string in this case I'll answer my question

Comment: Asking same question in different threads

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I forgot that the date is not yet converted to string for it to be subtracted

```
    @foreach($myquery as $mydate)
    <tr>
        <td>{{date('l',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{date('jS F, Y',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{$date1=date('h:i A',strtotime($mydate->logon))}}</td>
        <td>{{$date2=date('h:i A',strtotime($mydate->logoff))}}</td>
        <td>{{$date2-$date1}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: got a problem again, I'm getting negative results